# How to add a resume countdown to a game in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am making a 2D app in Unity similar to any "dodge the falling objects". I have added a pause function, but I want to add a countdown timer after you exit the pause menu. What I have right now is something like this:

```
public void Pressed () {
    if (Time.timeScale == 0) {
        pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
        countdown.text = "3";
        yield WaitForSeconds(1);
        // repeat for 2 and 1
        Time.timeScale = currentTimeScale;
    } else {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        pauseMenu.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on what the proper way to code this particular countdown is, or how to just fix mine in general would be very helpful.
Thanks!
-Brandon

Comment: Is that `yield WaitForSeconds(1);` working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already many implementations of count down timers. For example, see [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/11939/count-down-timer.html) and [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/980339/count-down-timer-c-1.html).

The general idea is to use a int field to save the remaining time. Or use `yield WaitForSeconds(1)` inside a coroutine to save the state.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WaitForSecondsExample : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(CountDown());
    }

    IEnumerator CountDown() {
        countdown.text = "3";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        countdown.text = "2";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        countdown.text = "1";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        //time up, now resume the app
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As for how to pause the app, see [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7544/how-do-i-pause-my-game.html) and [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/948536/view.html).

> [`Time.realtimeSinceStartup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html) returns the time since startup, not affected by Time.timeScale.

```
public static class CoroutineUtilities 
{
     public static IEnumerator WaitForRealTime(float delay){
        while(true){
            float pauseEndTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup + delay;
            while (Time.realtimeSinceStartup < pauseEndTime){
                yield return 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Usabilty:

```
 yield return StartCoroutine(CoroutineUtilities.WaitForRealTime(1));
```

Then we use `yield return StartCoroutine(CoroutineUtilities.WaitForRealTime(1))` instead of `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1)` in the code above:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WaitForSecondsExample : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(CountDown());
    }

    IEnumerator CountDown() {
        countdown.text = "3";
        yield return StartCoroutine(CoroutineUtilities.WaitForRealTime(1));
        countdown.text = "2";
        yield return StartCoroutine(CoroutineUtilities.WaitForRealTime(1));
        countdown.text = "1";
        yield return StartCoroutine(CoroutineUtilities.WaitForRealTime(1));
        //time up, now resume the app
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this coroutine won't work if you set timecale to zero. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Yes, you are partially right. [Set timescale to zero stops ` WaitForSeconds`.](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/276359/view.html)